# JavaFX User-drawn lines

Tags: java, javafx

How would I let a user draw lines on a `canvas` in JavaFX? I define a line as where the mouse went over between a click and a release. I'm thinking of using a mouse event handler and a `Path`, but I was wondering if there's anything built in that I could use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a small program that allows the user to draw lines from a tree on the left to a tree on tree on the right.

If the user clicks on an item in the left tree, a line is drawn and the endpoint is bound to the mouse position (a custom handler is registered to monitor for mouse movement and updates two properties that allow you to bind to it). This works great.

Comment: So what did you use to record the path the mouse took?

Comment: In my case I only needed the "current" position of the mouse because I'm drawing a straight line. So I simply bound the endpoints to the current position. However in your case you could keep a history of mouse positions and use it real time or use it after the drag is done and request it.